# Who was called?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have mobile data with the persons Name, the date of the call, the from_number and the to_number.
I need to have the association of the person's name that was called.

That is, if I have Barbara calling from number x  to number y then I want to know to whom that y or to_number belongs to?

Below is an example data_set:

```
SELECT  'Barbara'   AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,'022445544' AS From_Number, '022445545' AS To_Number UNION
SELECT  'Barbara'   AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,'091234123' AS From_Number, '022445545' AS To_Number UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,    '03123456'  AS From_Number, '08007543'  AS To_Number    UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,    '03123456'  AS From_Number, '022445555' AS To_Number    UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445545' AS From_Number, '091234123' AS To_Number    UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445545' AS From_Number, '022445555' AS To_Number    UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445545' AS From_Number, '049876543' AS To_Number    UNION
SELECT  'David' AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,    '049876543' AS From_Number, '022445544' AS To_Number    UNION
SELECT  'David' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445555' AS From_Number, '022445545' AS To_Number
```

I tried this:

```
select * 
   ,case when [From_Number] =[To_Number] then [Person] end as [from person]
   from [dbo].[cellphone]
```

but I think the problem is that I don't know, how would you express that SQL needs to look for all possible numbers among one person of each person, because Barbara for example has many different phone numbers. So as if I would look for a range of numbers to pinpoint the caller number? Sometimes, of course we do not have any association as the number is unknown to us. This would then need to be noted as unknown number.

The desired dataset outcome should look like this:

```
SELECT  'Barbara'   AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,'022445544' AS From_Number, '022445545' AS To_Number,'Peter'  AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'Barbara'   AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,'091234123' AS From_Number, '022445545' AS To_Number, 'Peter'    AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,    '03123456'  AS From_Number, '08007543'  AS To_Number, 'unkn'     AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,    '03123456'  AS From_Number, '022445555' AS To_Number,   'David'  AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445545' AS From_Number, '091234123' AS To_Number,   'Barbara'AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445545' AS From_Number, '022445555' AS To_Number,   'David'  AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'Peter' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445545' AS From_Number, '049876543' AS To_Number,   'David'  AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'David' AS Person,  '2020-07-03'    AS Date,    '049876543' AS From_Number, '022445544' AS To_Number,   'Barbara'AS person_called UNION
SELECT  'David' AS Person,  '2020-07-04'    AS Date,    '022445555' AS From_Number, '022445545' AS To_Number ,  'Peter'  AS person_called 


I also tried this : 



   SELECT A.Person, A.Date, A.From_Number, A.To_Number      
    ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT B.Person, B.Date, B.From_Number, B.To_Number FROM [dbo].[mobile_data] B 
                        WHERE B.From_Number = A.To_Number)
    THEN B.Person = A.Person    ELSE 'Unknown'   END as caller_id
   from [dbo].[mobile_data] a
```

But I get the following Error MSG: `The multi-part identifier "B.Person" could not be bound.` Essentially I need : THEN B.Person ELSE
But even if I try this It says that  B.Person cannot be bound.
Where is the syntax mistake?

Comment: Please show your desired results for the provided sample data.

Comment: Create a temporary table.

```SELECT A.Person, 
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 B WHERE B.From_Number = A.To_Number)
    THEN (SELECT From_Number FROM table2 B WHERE B.From_Number = A.To_Number)
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END
FROM
  table1 A
```

Didn't test, but you'll need to check to see if the number exists by creating a subquery and using a case statement, then grabbing it in the positive scenario or returning an Unknown as a string, if I understood correctly. You'll need to add more, of course.

Comment: Are you aware that the information you have isn't sufficient to answer that question in all cases? With the data you have, you can only get the name associated with the call recipient number if that person has also made an outgoing call at some point.

Comment: @allmhuran - Yes, absolutely, the caller name can of course only be obtained if the caller name has made an outgoing call at any point in time (within the dataset). But that is what we want to know. Essentially, it is about who knows whom as far as we can see it? Everything else goes into the unkn bucket.

Comment: OK, just making sure. As a hint to get started, remember that you can join a table to itself.  So if your table is called `calls`, you can do a `select ... from calls as callers join calls as recipients on ...`, and fill in the logic for that join (hint, you'll be joining on the two phone number columns). Does that get you started?

Comment: @DanielCazares I am playing around with this: 
 SELECT A.Person, A.Date, A.From_Number, A.To_Number      
    ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT B.Person, B.Date, B.From_Number, B.To_Number FROM [dbo].[mobile_data] B 
                     WHERE B.From_Number = A.To_Number)
 THEN B.Person = A.Person ELSE 'Unknown'   END as caller_id
   from [dbo].[mobile_data] a
 
 -- it is not happy with this:  B.Person = A.Person ELSE    Error MSG:  The multi-part identifier "A.To_Number" could not be bound. How can you assign the B.Person ?

Comment: That's a good attempt. You should update your question to include that attempt as formatted code, and the error message, rather than putting it as a comment. Also, given your update to include the "unknowns", read my "hint" comment as `left join` instead of `join` (but it could also be done your way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me change the format of your query so it's a bit easier for me to add comments in useful spots.

```sql
  select A.Person, 
         A.Date, 
         A.From_Number, 
         A.To_Number,
         case
            when exists 
            (
               select   B.Person, B.Date, B.From_Number, B.To_Number 
               from     [dbo].[mobile_data] B 
               where    B.From_Number = A.To_Number
               -- the bit after "then" must  be the value you want if the "when" condition is true.
               -- the expression "b.person = a.person" isn't a value, it's either a check whether two things are equal,
               -- or an assignment from the thing on the right hand side to the thing on the left hand side
            ) then B.Person = A.Person 
            else 'Unknown'  
          end as caller_id
   -- This "from" clause only includes the alias "a". There's no "b" alias here. 
   -- So you can't refer to anything from "b" in this outer select.
   -- "b" only lives inside the "exists" condition above, it can't be seen from out here
   -- but you referred to b outside the "exists" condition, in the "then B.Person = A.Person ". 
   -- That's why SQL is saying that the "b.person" identifier could not be bound (it can't see it out here).
   from [dbo].[mobile_data] a
```

In order to answer your question in the way I think you want, we have to make an assertion: A single person can have many phone numbers, but a single phone number can only belong to one person.

If this is correct, we can take those calls and join them back onto themselves to get the answer. We will take the callers `to_number`, and try to match that to someone else's `from_number`. If we don't get a match, then the person being called has not themselves made any calls, so we don't know who they are.

We have to use `distinct` as well, because a person can make multiple calls. For example, Barbara called the number 022445544, which belongs to Peter. But peter has made 4 calls, so we'll match Barbara's call to all of those calls peter made. But of course, in all 4 of those calls it is Peter who is making it, so if we use `distinct` we'll just get one Peter, which is what we want.

```sql
create table calls 
(
   from_name varchar(32),
   call_date date,
   from_number varchar(16),
   to_number varchar(16)
);

insert   calls
values   ('Barbara', '2020-07-03','022445544',  '022445545'),
         ('Barbara', '2020-07-03','091234123',  '022445545'),
         ('Peter',   '2020-07-03','03123456',   '08007543'),
         ('Peter',   '2020-07-03','03123456',   '022445555'),
         ('Peter',   '2020-07-04','022445545',  '091234123'),
         ('Peter',   '2020-07-04','022445545',  '022445555'),
         ('Peter',   '2020-07-04','022445545',  '049876543'),
         ('David',   '2020-07-03','049876543',  '022445544'),
         ('David',   '2020-07-04','022445555',  '022445545');

select      distinct
            callers.*,
            to_name = isnull(recipients.from_name, 'unkn')
from        calls    callers
left join   calls    recipients on recipients.from_number = callers.to_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an online REPL and setup the table first.

```
CREATE TABLE people
( Person VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Date VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  From_Number VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  To_Number VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
insert into people values('Barbara','2020-07-03','022445544','022445545');
insert into people values('Barbara','2020-07-03','091234123','022445545');
insert into people values('Peter','2020-07-03','03123456','08007543');
insert into people values('Peter','2020-07-03','03123456','022445555');
insert into people values('Peter','2020-07-04','022445545','091234123');
insert into people values('Peter','2020-07-04','022445545','022445555');
insert into people values('Peter','2020-07-04','022445545','049876543');
insert into people values('David','2020-07-03','049876543','022445544');
insert into people values('David','2020-07-04','022445555','022445545');
```

Then, used the following query.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM people B WHERE B.From_Number = A.To_Number)
        THEN (SELECT Person FROM people B WHERE B.From_Number = A.To_Number)
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END Person_Called
FROM people A
```

That gave me the following result.

```
Barbara|2020-07-03|022445544|022445545|Peter
Barbara|2020-07-03|091234123|022445545|Peter
Peter|2020-07-03|03123456|08007543|Unknown
Peter|2020-07-03|03123456|022445555|David
Peter|2020-07-04|022445545|091234123|Barbara
Peter|2020-07-04|022445545|022445555|David
Peter|2020-07-04|022445545|049876543|David
David|2020-07-03|049876543|022445544|Barbara
David|2020-07-04|022445555|022445545|Peter
```

Comment: Hi @DanielCazares, thank you for the tip. It did not work for the main query, because some people have up to 3 phone numbers. I did think that adding an ID (as in: ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) )could solve this. But I could not implement this into my view. Not sure you can. But still valid input!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
cellphone
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
    ( 'Barbara', '03-Jul-2020', '022445544', '022445545')
   , ( 'Barbara', '03-Jul-2020', '091234123', '022445545')
   , ( 'David', '03-Jul-2020', '049876543', '022445544')
   , ( 'David', '04-Jul-2020', '022445555', '022445545')
   , ( 'Peter', '03-Jul-2020', '03123456', '022445555')
   , ( 'Peter', '03-Jul-2020', '03123456', '08007543')
   , ( 'Peter', '04-Jul-2020', '022445545', '022445555')
   , ( 'Peter', '04-Jul-2020', '022445545', '049876543')
   , ( 'Peter', '04-Jul-2020', '022445545', '091234123')
   ) tbl ([Person], [Date], [From_Number], [To_Number]) 
)
, 
person_cellphone
AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Person]
      , [From_Number]
   FROM 
      cellphone
)
SELECT 
     cel.[Person]
    , cel.[Date]
    , cel.[From_Number]
    , cel.[To_Number]
    , [To_Number] = ISNULL(pct.[Person], '<N/A>')
FROM 
   cellphone AS cel
   LEFT JOIN person_cellphone AS pct ON pct.[From_Number] = cel.[To_Number]
```

[image]